# Spacing between icon and label in tabbedpage bar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, tabbedpage

[image: 2nd question: How to remove lines after last list item and how to change the color of the icon?]

I have a tabbedPage where I'm assigning text and icons for each tab as follows:

```
this.Children.Add(new SignaturesTab() { Title = "Signature" , Icon 
= "sign_new@2x.png" });
this.Children.Add(new PhotosTab() { Title = "Photos", Icon = 
"image_new@2x.png" });
```

On my iPhone, icon appears top of the label in the bar for each tab.

Code in Tab Renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        TabBar.TintColor = new UIColor(red: 0.23f, green: 0.56f, blue: 0.20f, alpha: 1.0f);
        TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = new UIColor(red: 0.34f, green: 0.34f, blue: 0.34f, alpha: 1.0f);
    }

public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        if (TabBar.Items == null) return;
        TabBar.SelectedImageTintColor = new UIColor(red: 0.23f, green: 0.56f, blue: 0.20f, alpha: 1.0f);
        foreach (var uiTabBarItem in TabBar.Items)
        {
            var fontSize = new UITextAttributes(){ Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(13)};
            uiTabBarItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(fontSize, UIControlState.Normal);
        } 
    }
```

Is there a way to provide spacing/margin between icon and label and to the borders.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using **UIOffset** and **UIEdgeInsets** can modify posittion of `Title` and `Image` in `TabBarItem` .

```
TabBarItem.TitlePositionAdjustment = new UIOffset(0, 1);
//UIOffset:Represents a position offset. UIOffset(nfloat horizontal, nfloat vertical);

TabBarItem.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 5, 0);
//Mean: UIEdgeInsets(nfloat top, nfloat left, nfloat bottom, nfloat right);
```

Modifying paramaters inside `UIOffset` and `UIEdgeInsets` to fit your want.

=============================Update==============================

Changing tab bar item icon color :

```
UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Yellow;
//selected color ,this will change the whole tabbar item
```

Just four items be modified :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   var fontSize = new UITextAttributes(){ Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(13)};
   uiTabBarItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(fontSize, UIControlState.Normal);
   uiTabBarItem.TitlePositionAdjustment = new UIOffset(0, 1);
   uiTabBarItem.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 5, 0);
}
```

Comment: I will try this. Also, I have total 8 tabs. And on my iphone, it shows 5th tab as "More". Clicking on More tab it opens a page which has remaining tabs in the form of list. All the icon colors in this page are blue and list separator line is all over the page. can we handle this list separators for only this 4 items and change the icon colors?

Comment: @SaiSunkari This seems like another problem.You can share some image in question to explain your want.

Comment: can you please check the edited question. Sorry for mixing up 2 questions. @Junior

Comment: @SaiSunkari Thanks for updating. I have updated answer , if be helpful , thanks for marking in advance.

Comment: looks like you provided answer to update color of the 1st four tab bar items. My requirement is to remove list separator lines and change color from blue to default i.e.; black. correct me if I'm wrong. @Junior

Comment: @SaiSunkari Maybe you can create a new question about removing list separator lines and share detail explain where you want to change in image. The title of the current question does not match the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

I make a trick with IBDesignable for doing that.
may it useful for you

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomTabBarItem: UITabBarItem {

    @IBInspectable var titlePosition: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) {
        didSet {
            titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: titlePosition.width, vertical: titlePosition.height)
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var imageInset: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0) {
        didSet {
            imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: imageInset.origin.x, left: imageInset.origin.y, bottom: imageInset.size.width, right: imageInset.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```