# How to make multiline text on tab items in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I got 5 tabs on `TabbedPage` & last 2 tabs have long title name, on Android, it shows 3dots as ... when there is no more room space remaining for text.

eg.

> ```
> tab 1 title - Title 1 for Tab1
> tab 2 title - Title 2 for Tab2
> tab 3 title - Title 3 for Tab3
>  Android - Title 1 f... | Title 2 f... | Title 3 f...
> ```

But on iOS it doesn't show 3dots, it shows complete text which can even override the title of another tab. Kind of text overlapping.

Basically I want my title of TabbedPage on multi-line, I use different content pages as tabs for my TabbedPage.
I can create MultiLine ContentPage n its working fine on its own. But when I set the MultiLine title content page as a tab for my TabbedPage, it only shows the first-line title.

Any solution for MultiLine TabbedPage Title on iOS like below
[image: Image from Junior Jiang - MSFT]

My Current renderer code

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer( typeof( TabbedPage ), typeof(ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer ) )]
 namespace testBlu.iOS.Renderers
 {
   public class ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
   {
    public override void ViewDidAppear( bool animated )
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear( animated );
        if( TabBar.Items != null )
        {
            UITabBarItem[] tabs = TabBar.Items;
            foreach( UITabBarItem tab in tabs )
            {
                UITextAttributes selectedColor = new UITextAttributes { TextColor = UIColor.Black };
                UITextAttributes fontSize = new UITextAttributes { Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize( 12 )};
                tab.SetTitleTextAttributes( selectedColor, UIControlState.Normal );
                tab.SetTitleTextAttributes( fontSize, UIControlState.Normal );
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If need to show three dots the same with Android , here is a solution for you . Later if have solution for multi-lines will update here .

You can use [Custom TabbedRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) to implement it .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace AppTab3.iOS
{
    public class ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
            if(tabs != null)
            {
                for( int i = 0;i < TabBar.Items.Length;i++)
                {
                    if (TabBar.Items[i] == null) return;

                    if(TabBar.Items[i].Title.Length > 6)
                    {
                        string showText = TabBar.Items[i].Title;
                        TabBar.Items[i].Title = showText.Substring(0, 5) + "...";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here `MainPage` inside code is a `TabbedPage` ：`public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage`

And here I set the limited length of TabBar Text is `6` . The **Xaml** is as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:AppTab3.Views"
            x:Class="AppTab3.Views.MainPage">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Browse">

            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

      ...

        <NavigationPage Title="Page Five Long Title Page Five Long Title">
            <NavigationPage.TitleView>
                 <Label Text="About Five Long Title" MaxLines="4"/>
            </NavigationPage.TitleView>
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS"
                        Value="tab_about.png" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AboutPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

    </TabbedPage.Children>

</TabbedPage>
```

The effect :

[image]

================================Update=============================

I have found the way to implement multiline title in tabbar item , need to modify code in `TabbedRenderer` as follow :

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;

    if (tabs != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
        {

            if (TabBar.Items[i] == null) continue;

            if (TabBar.Items[i].Title.Length > 6)
            {
                string[] splitTitle = TabBar.Items[i].Title.Split(" ");
                TabBar.Items[i].Title = splitTitle[0] + "\n" + splitTitle[1];

                UITabBarItem item = TabBar.Items[i] as UITabBarItem;
                UIView view = item.ValueForKey(new Foundation.NSString("view")) as UIView;
                UILabel label = view.Subviews[1] as UILabel;
                //label.Text = "Hello\nWorld!";
                label.Lines = 2;
                label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;

                //var frame = label.Frame;
                //label.Frame = CGRect.FromLTRB(frame.Location.X, frame.Location.Y, frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height + 20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

**Note** : Althouh this way can implement it , however Apple not recommands to do this . It will affect the beauty of interface ,and make the frame of Tabbar item's shape distortion .

=============================Update with shared code=======================

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;

    if (tabs != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
        {

            if (TabBar.Items[i] == null) continue;

            if (TabBar.Items[i].Title.Length > 6)
            {
                string[] splitTitle = TabBar.Items[i].Title.Split(" ");
                if (null != splitTitle[1])
                {
                    if (splitTitle[1].Length > 4)
                    {
                        string showText = splitTitle[1];
                        splitTitle[1] = showText.Substring(0, 3) + "...";
                    }
                }

                TabBar.Items[i].Title = splitTitle[0] + "\n" + splitTitle[1];

                UITabBarItem item = TabBar.Items[i] as UITabBarItem;
                UITextAttributes selectedColor = new UITextAttributes { TextColor = UIColor.Black };
                UITextAttributes fontSize = new UITextAttributes { Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12) };
                item.SetTitleTextAttributes(selectedColor, UIControlState.Selected);
                item.SetTitleTextAttributes(fontSize, UIControlState.Selected);

                UIView view = item.ValueForKey(new Foundation.NSString("view")) as UIView;
                UILabel label = view.Subviews[1] as UILabel;
                //label.Text = "Hello\nWorld!";
                label.Lines = 2;
                label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;

                //var frame = label.Frame;
                //label.Frame = CGRect.FromLTRB(frame.Location.X, frame.Location.Y, frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height + 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try n then confirm you about it.

Comment: @Blu Hi , I have found the solution to make multiline title for TabbedPage in iOS , you can have a look at it when you have time. But you should know that Apple not recommand developer to modify that designs .

Comment: Hi, actually i tried your code but its crashing my app as an exception `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` for line `UILabel label = view.Subviews[1] as UILabel`..an UpVote for the help :)

Comment: I have edited my question with the current code i'm having. And i need exactly what you showed in your screen shot! thanks

Comment: @Blu OK, If Tabbar Item not contains icon , you should get label from index `0` , for example :`UILabel label = view.Subviews[0] as UILabel ` .

Comment: @Blu I have updated answer with combining your shared code . In my local site , I need to set `UILabel label = view.Subviews[1] as UILabel`  . You can get from index `0` to check whehter can get .

Comment: yesterday I tried with UILabel label = view.Subviews[1] as UILabel; it got crashed, but work with UILabel label = view.Subviews[0] as UILabel; but my partial label was visible, mean - "Sample /n Title" so only "Sample" is visible.

Comment: i will try it in some time maybe. cuz i have to work on clients android issue...THANKS once again :)

Comment: this works, however the tabbed buttons are not aligned, in 2020 - and still no usable solution for this. Xamarin is poor

Comment: @Async- Okey , this is not related to Xamarin. Apple not suggests that make multiline title in tabbar item . If need that effects , you can this `uiTabBarItem.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 5, 0)` to modify the space of needed tababr item between label and icon . Have a look at this discussuion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260325/spacing-between-icon-and-label-in-tabbedpage-bar/57263848#57263848 :-)

Comment: what I mean is the "final" solution can not offer the icons to be aligned (check how icons all jump heights because the label's have different length - one word or two words) - besides that I see in my project that if first word is shorter of the two - "Page eleven" - the second word will be cut to only 4 letters (label width is calculated from first word, no idea why), and will be "Page elev" - check it yourself. Besides, this is the only solution to the problem I found, meaning community Xamarin is lacking numbers, you will be on your own with your problems. Developers should avoid Xamarin.

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT I do use UIEdgeInsets, that only constraints the image within edges, doesn't help with alignment of the icons where labels have different lengths.

Comment: @Async- These are iOS limitations, not specific to Xamarin. Regardless of language, [some workaround code is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60320339/199364). Could adapt the code shown there to C#. Or add spaces and newline so that all tabs have "similar" text. E.g. `"Page   \neleven"`, and change code in answer to split on newline instead of space. Force all to be two line: `"About\n     "`, to avoid "uneven" height (jumping). Any workaround has nothing to do with Xamarin; Xamarin simply uses the built-in iOS control.

Answer (score -1):

I think the most simple way (i.e, avoiding a custom renderer) would be to use a **TitleView**

Here's the official Microsoft sample.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-titleview/

Here's a blog post.
https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-title-view-a-powerful-navigation-view

In that TitleView you can use a **Label** and set the [LineBreakMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.linebreakmode?view=xamarin-forms) property.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I already knew that & I have already mentioned it clearly, I can do what you suggested but I need something else. Please read it again carefully.

Comment: If by "mentioned it clearly", you mean "I can create MultiLine ContentPage n its working fine on its own" then fair enough. Other than that, I don't see any mention of the word "TitleView". I've read it multiple times. Regardless, you should just be able to apply the TitleView to your TabbedPage instead of a ContentPage. If you provide a sample of your code I'm happy to look further.

Comment: @rssllgrrtt Hi , have you solved it ? If need with three dots , I have a solution . However now no having a multi-line solution .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I've not looked since. I wasn't overly sure if the original poster was talking about the title of the page (the one you see at the top) or the title on the tab bar. Given that they didn't provide any additional info, code, or screenshots, and then I got a downvote, I figured I might as well leave this one alone. Good luck :)

Comment: @rssllgrrtt You're right . Blu not showing screenshot about queston , maybe your answer will be Blu's wants .

Comment: IMHO, the reason this answer got downvoted is that the original title of the question was poor. I've edited that title to clarify that it is "tab item text" that is wanted multiline, NOT "title of page".